# S3のリストをReactで表示させたい

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3

AWSのあるバケットに入っているオブジェクトの一覧をReactで表示させたいです。
Javascript S3等で調べてみましたが、わかりやすいものがなく、困っております。
S3への接続するのがまず第一段階でなんとかしたいです。

WebアプリケーションはAmplifyで作成していて、Amplifyのコンポーネントで使えるものがあれば良かったのですが、いまいちでした。

よい参考になるサイトでも結構です。
どなたか助けてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

次のAWSのドキュメントを調べてみてはいかがでしょうか。

[AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://aws.amazon.com/jp/sdk-for-javascript/)
[React Nativeで始める](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/sdk-for-javascript/v3/developer-guide/getting-started-react-native.html)

Comment: AWS SDKのリファレンスを読むことにしました。有難うございます。